# Get number of unread messages using a timestamp

Tags: javascript, time

I am currently keeping track of unread messages in a React application using `state`; However, I was told I should instead store the time stamp of the last viewed message and compare it to the time stamps that corresponds to a message and get a count from that.

To achieve this, I was thinking I would increment a counter or store in array every time a message timestamp is greater than the last viewed time stamp. I don't see how this would be any different than simply using a state as a counter unless there is a better way to get total number of unread messages by using a last viewed timestamp with the timestamps for each new message.

Comment: I don't see code and I don't see a question

Comment: Well, logically, if you have 10 unread messages and you read the most recent message, your counter's going to reset to zero if you do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like for your purposes, a date and `state` or counter property would be the same. One thing to consider, is for messages, most applications associate messages with timestamps or dates. So, as an end-user, if I were looking for a message or to filter messages, I would probably do it by date/timestamp. Making the property you're reading a date/timestamp just makes it easier to potentially use that timestamp later, and it serves the same purpose as your counter or `state` property.